# asp.net - create ordered editorfor model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know that we can use this in razor asp.net mvc 4

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Parameters)
```

But what if we want to render the parameters ordered by parameters.displayOrder

I have tried with

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Parameters.OrderBy(p => p.displayOrder))
```

but it is not possible to do operations to the model inside razor.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in the view we can do this

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.Name;
    Model.Parameters.OrderBy(p => p.DisplayOrder);
}
```

Thus the child collection will be ordered

Answer (score 0):

Logically, if first do the job, so why to not adapt second case to the first one, mean apply ordering on model level (before rendering).